# iPhone: Cannot get simulator to generate .gcda profiling data files

Tags: iphone, profiling, gcov

I'm attempting to profile my code using the iPhone simulator. I've enabled **Generate Test Coverage File** and **Instrument Program Flow** and added **-lgcov** to the linker flags. According to everything I've read that should be all I need to do in terms of setup.

Update: **Generate Test Coverage File** triggers the **-ftest-coverage** flag and **Instrument Program Flow** triggers the **-fprofile-arcs** flag. I've checked the build logs and they are being set when compiling.

Executing the program I can see the ***.gcno*** files appearing along side the **.o** compiled code in the build/.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/.build/Objects-normal/i386 directory.

But when I run the app in the simulator I do not get any ***.gcda** files appearing.

My understanding is that these files contain the data from the instrumentation. But I cannot find them anywhere on the computer.

I know they can be produced and appear along side the ***.gcno** files because I have an old trashed buil directory which does have them. I just cannot figure out what I have to do to get them to appear and record the run.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to find and get rid of "bottlenecks"? If so, [consider random-pausing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773).

Comment: No. My main interest is in seeing how much of the application is covered by unit tests and helping me to pin point areas I would like to add more testing to. Coming from a java/agile background, unit testing is something I like to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Cross_002dprofiling.html) would give you some idea. Exploring the link I found

> The .gcno file is generated when the
> source file is compiled with the GCC
> -ftest-coverage option. It contains information to reconstruct the basic
> block graphs and assign source line
> numbers to blocks.
>
> The .gcda file is generated when a
> program containing object files built
> with the GCC -fprofile-arcs option is
> executed. A separate .gcda file is
> created for each object file compiled
> with this option. It contains arc
> transition counts, and some summary
> information.

So may be you are building with some wrong settings. The information is mentioned on http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-Data-Files.html#Gcov-Data-Files

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iOSGCov) may have the answer, basically gcda files are not generated until your app exits properly.  It gives two possible solutions:

- completely quit the simulator
- add this to your plist (but not for release builds):

  ```
  <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
  <true/>
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both of those solutions. Fully shutting down the simulator and then adding that line to the plist. Neither worked.

Comment: Just tried removing the prefix header. Didn't fix the issue. Even when I exited the simulator as well.

Comment: I think the problem is building with wrong settings. He is getting gcno files which appear with `GCC -ftest-coverage` option, he need to build with `GCC -fprofile-arcs` option to get the gcda files.

Comment: @Madhup - Sorry, I'm definitely building with -fprofile-arcs.